# Is Java Contradicting Itself?

Tags: java, math, fractions

Should I declare `Math.round(1/2)` in Java to be an int or a double? If both are fine, which is more correct?

Also, why is it that Eclipse is telling me Math.round(1/2) = 0.0, while Math.round(0.5) = 1.0 ?

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The compiler starts by evaluating the expression 1/2.  Both those numbers are integers, so it does integer math.  In integers, 1 divided by 2 is 0.  Then, it casts the 0 to a double in order to pass it to Math.round().

If you want a correct answer, you need to pass in doubles: you can do this by using 1.0/2.0 instead of 1/2.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you for this answer. If I HAD to declare Math.round(1/2) equal to a variable, would it matter if I used an int or double? Which would be more correct?

Comment: @Hannah P, It would not be correct, regardless of which variable type you use. Btw you can use just `1.0/2` or `1d/2`

Answer (score 6):

`1/2` is 0, because it is an integer expression.

If you want the floating point value, say `1.0/2.0` (or just `1./2`).